# Mysql statement to select entries in date range

Tags: mysql

I have a table with activities:

```
id (int)
day (int)
activity_date (datetime)
```

I add new activities this way:

```
insert into activities values
(null, 1, '2015-01-01 10:00:00'),
(null, 1, '2015-01-01 11:00:00'),
(null, 1, '2015-01-01 12:00:00'),
(null, 2, '2015-01-02 10:00:00'),
(null, 2, '2015-01-02 11:00:00'),
(null, 2, '2015-01-02 12:00:00');
```

I added 6 entries. 3 activities for day 1 and 3 activities for day 2.
Now, I want to fetch all the activities that are for the day that "right now" still has to take place.
Example:

Right now time is:

```
2015-01-01 10:50:00
```

As day 1 contains an entry that is "in the range" (activities at 11:00 and 12:00 has to take place)
I want to select all the activities for day 1.

I tried using "between". But just doing like

```
select * from activities where now() between activity_date
```

gives sql-error.

EDIT:

Please note that a "day" can span across several days. So the entries can be:

```
insert into activities values
(null, 2, '2015-09-12 10:00:00'),
(null, 2, '2015-09-12 18:00:00'),
(null, 2, '2015-09-12 20:45:00'),
(null, 2, '2015-09-13 20:45:00');
```

As now it is

```
2015-09-12 22:45:00
```

the solution suggested by vhu doesnt work completely. His suggestion was:

```
SELECT * FROM activities
WHERE activity_date >= NOW() 
AND DATE(activity_date) = DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM activities
 WHERE activity_date >= NOW() 
  AND DATE(activity_date) = DATE(NOW());
```

This will give you all activities that haven't yet occurred but are for today.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I missed something in the description. So it actually doesnt work. I will update he description.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I assume you want something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM activities x 
           JOIN activities y 
             ON DATE(y.activity_date) = DATE(x.activity_date) 
          WHERE DATE(y.activity_date) = DATE('2015-01-01 10:50:00') 
            AND y.activity_date > '2015-01-01 10:50:00';
```

Note that on indexed data, rewriting this using range comparisons will be more efficient.